# Sinon stub.resolves() not acting as desired

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sinon

Here's the function I'm writing tests for:

```
ensureUserDoesNotExist(request, response, next) {
  this.User.findOne({ where: { email: request.body.email }})
    .then(user => {
      if (user) {
        response.sendStatus(403);
      } else {
        next();
      }
    });
  }
```

And here's the test that I cannot get to pass:

```
it('should return a 403 if a matching user is found', () => {
  mockRequest.body.email = 'test@email.com';
  userController.User.findOne.resolves(true); // This is a previously created sinon stub
  userController.ensureUserDoesNotExist(mockRequest, mockResponse, mockNext);
  assert(mockResponse.sendStatus.calledWith(403));
});
```

It fails, simply claiming that the stub isn't called (at all, for what it's worth).

I strongly suspect this is to do with the promise - or Sinon's interaction with it - but am having a complete mind-blank in trying to figure out exactly what. The code works as intended (or it did when I last looked before playing about with it). Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assertion is evaluated before the end request
You need to return the promise

```
ensureUserDoesNotExist(request, response, next) {
  return this.User.findOne({ where: { email: request.body.email }})
    .then(user => {
      if (user) {
        response.sendStatus(403);
      } else {
        next();
      }
    });
  }
```

and assert in `then` clause

```
it('should return a 403 if a matching user is found', () => {
  mockRequest.body.email = 'test@email.com';
  userController.User.findOne.resolves(true); // This is a previously created sinon stub
  userController.ensureUserDoesNotExist(mockRequest, mockResponse, mockNext).then(() => {
     assert(mockResponse.sendStatus.calledWith(403));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The test also must return a promise to indicate an asynchronous test to Mocha. You can use the one returned by the `then` call:

```
it('should return a 403 if a matching user is found', () => {
  mockRequest.body.email = 'test@email.com';
  userController.User.findOne.resolves(true); // This is a previously created sinon stub
  return userController.ensureUserDoesNotExist(mockRequest, mockResponse, mockNext).then(() => {
      assert(mockResponse.sendStatus.calledWith(403));
  });
});
```